# output is proper but showing runtime error in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{ 
    int i = -1, j = 1,k,l;
    k=!i&&j;
    l= !i||j;
    printf("\n%d\n%d",i,j);
}
```

shows in output: `Runtime error time: 0 memory: 10304 signal:-1`

but if i replace void by int and add return 0 in program it works fine without any error why?

Comment: `void main()` is not a standard signature for `main`. It might work with *some* compilers. The only signatures guaranteed by the standard are `int main(void)` and `int main(int, char**)`.

Answer (score 0):

`void main()` is not described in the C11 Standard. Some implementations are free to "legalize" it. The implementation you are using is, apparently, sticking to the Standard in that regard.

Try `int main(void)` which is [mandated by the Standard to be correct (C11, 5.1.2.2.1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1).